# C# Dependency Injection with DNN Version 9.9 in a Web Forms project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am trying to get my hands around using Dependency Injection with DNN.  I looked at the DotNetNuke.Startup class and see the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<WebFormsModuleControlFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<Html5ModuleControlFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<ReflectedModuleControlFactory>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDnnContext, DotNetNukeContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IEventLogger, EventLogController>();
    services.AddScoped<IEventLogConfigService, EventLogController>();
    services.AddScoped<IEventLogService, EventLogController>();
    services.AddTransient((IServiceProvider x) => ServiceLocator<IPortalController, PortalController>.Instance);
    services.AddScoped<IHostSettingsService, HostController>();
    services.AddScoped<INavigationManager, NavigationManager>();
    services.AddScoped<ISerializationManager, SerializationManager>();
    services.AddScoped<IApplicationInfo, DotNetNuke.Application.Application>();
    services.AddScoped<IApplicationStatusInfo, ApplicationStatusInfo>();
    services.AddScoped<IPortalAliasService, PortalAliasController>();
}
```

I have an understanding on how to wire up those services, but my confusion comes into play on how to register other dependencies that are not specific to DNN services for a Web Forms application (a new custom service).

Does anyone have any experience with this? In my Web Forms project, do I have to create a new Startup class that inherits the DNN Interface for Startup?  Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing Dependency Injection from WebForms with DNN is ever so slightly different, but [this article provides the step-by-step](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/dnn-dependency-injection-webforms-modules) instructions on using it in your project.

The short summary is you create your own registration class using `IDnnStartup` and then use the Service Locator to get the instance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Can you please help me understand how the registration class will get invoked? For example, if I created a new class named Startup.cs that uses IDnnStartup, where do I place that file and how does it get invoked?  If I have a Web.UI project and want to utilize DI in that project, I am missing the concept of where to place  Startup.cs and invoking it?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I use to inject a specific dependency, in this case the event logger. I know this is not answering your question directly, but it should point you in the right direction.

```
using DotNetNuke.Abstractions;
using DotNetNuke.Abstractions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace myCompany.DNN.Modules.myModule {
   private readonly IEventLogger _eventLogger;
   public class myControl {
      public myControl() {      // this is the constructor of the class
         _eventlogger = DependencyProvider.GetRequiredService<IEventLogger>();
      }
   }

   protected override void someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      try {
         // some code
      } catch(Exception ex) {
         _eventLogger.AddLog("Problem Getting Product Description, Title, or Image URL.", ex.ToString(), EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT);
      }
   }
}
```

And the link that Mitchel provided is very useful to understand Dependency Injection in DNN.